# How to write into Microsoft Access in hebrew?

Tags: java, database, ms-access

Hay Im trying to write into my database table in hebrew from my java program but after I'm executing my query Im getting question marks instead of hebrew...

What should I do?

```
String query="INSERT INTO client VALUES("'שלום'")";
rs.executeUpdate(query);
```

thanks to helpers :)

Comment: Can you show your code, and specify how exactly you're trying to do it?

Comment: What technology do you use to access the Access DB?

Comment: I read that I need to use utf-8 but I don't know where and how to use it...